# Desktop based application recording in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a desktop based(.exe) application used for trading of equities.

1.Developed  in VB uses TCP/IP.
2.Uses a database server which is an another server which the exe sends requests on.
3.I want to get the entire response using jmeter for 50 users at a time.

I wanted to record the responses for the transactions.I have worked with web applications where we create Http proxy server and start it and the recording happenes from browser but in this case i cant use browser.

Please guide me how to record the responses in jmeter with .exe applications.

Thanks and Regards,
Kumar

Answer (score 0):

JMeter [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder) is capable of recording only HTTP or HTTPS traffic so if following conditions are met:

1. Your .exe application talks to server using HTTP
2. Your .exe application can be configured to use HTTP proxy or respects Windows global HTTP Proxy settings from registry (or configured in Internet Explorer)

the answer is "yes", you can use JMeter to record the traffic. See [Load Testing Mobile Apps. But Made Easy.](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) guide for details on how to do it.

If one of above conditions cannot be satisfied there are following options available:

1. If you still want to use JMeter there is a possibility to use a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture requests and manually construct them using JMeter [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) or [TCP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler).
2. Consider switching to [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) tool which offers [TCP Proxy](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/tcpproxy.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there any way to directely record the responses from jmeter ?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the response just one question where to install the wireshark on the client or server ?

Comment: It doesn't matter where, it'll catch all the requests. I would go for client side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have installed wireshark on client machine.It is capturing the TCP source and destination IPs. While using TCP sampler in Jmeter iam confused what needs to be entered in the field "Text to Send" as iam not getting any text in wireshark. Thanks,Kumar

Comment: This question is outside JMeter. I would recommend using "Follow TCP Stream" context menu option to see requests. http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowTCPSection.html

Comment: Hi iam able to get the tcp request and responses now.The problem now is the requests that i get is encrypted and the server accepts the same encrypted requests.As a result iam not able to understand the values to be parameterzsed in that as it is not readable.If i have the encription logic given by the developers can i send request using that logic? if yes then how it is possible in Jmeter? Thanks,Kumar

Comment: It's possible but given application is developed with VB you won't be able to reuse encryption code directly. You'll have to implement it by yourself using JMeter Extension mechanism and one of supported languages. The most powerful of built-in is Beanshell. See http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell guide for clues. However if encryption is not proprietary and has Java implementations you can look add relevant library to JMeter classpath (if it's not already there)

Comment: so if i am using  Beanshell i need not to use TCP sampler to send request as i will be sending request from Beanshell right?

Comment: You can construct request in Beanshell and send it with TCP Sampler. Beanshell isn't getting compiled into native code and the code is being interpreted each time it's called.

Comment: Hi,I am sending request with TCP sampler in hex format from wireshark.iam getting the desired response.This request is for login to the application.Now iam trying to parameterize my script with other user ids for load testing with 500 users.How can i parameterize my user ids and send the request in hex format.i know the start and end byte and the lenght of the user id in my request but its in binary format.Can anyone help me how to parameterize my user ids in my request with csv file parameterization.

Comment: You can encode variables from CSV file on-the-fly using Beanshell. To provide details I need more information on what exact "hex" format does your application accepts.

Comment: it accepts data in the format like :    0000000000000001000000re01010034001100tr ......... and it has the user id also in this request i want to know how to parameterize my user id in such requests

Comment: thanks for your response it would be great if you please suggest me what details exactly you are looking for

Comment: please suggest how to go ahead on this ?

Comment: Hi i have done with scripting but getting read exception error.Where i can change tcp.BinaryTCPClient.eomByte parameter as i dont see any entry for the same in jmeter properties file.Do i need to add this line in the file?

Comment: please suggest on this